# Cassandra ring status when a node goes down

Tags: cassandra

I have a basic query.
Cassandra nodes always forms a ring, where each node communicate with their neighboring nodes, i.e. for any node they always gossip with two other nodes.

When a node goes down, the ring is broken. So to complete the ring, do the two neighboring nodes start gossiping with each other completing the ring ?

And which node will retain the hinted hand-off, only the neighboring nodes or any node in the ring ?

Thank You
Tapas Dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a Cassandra cluster is not a ring.
Cassandra nodes will always gossip to ALL other nodes not just 2.

The hinted handoff is stored locally in the coordinator node.
Hinted handoffs are stored because the coordinator found that a particular node was not contactable.

Here is a good explanation of hinted handoffs
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesHintedHandoff.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was in an assumption that Cassandra node always communicates with its neighboring nodes.
Then why they say Cassandra cluster always forms a Ring, what is the meaning of Ring here ?

Comment: Believe it's a mental way to think of the distributed token ranges among nodes forming a ring.